# How to open and close a pdf file from java?

Tags: java, pdf

```
    File f  = new File("D:\\New folder\\Assignment worksheet of MS Word.docx");
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);
```

I am trying to open and close a pdf file from java. I have succeeded to open that file using above code but I am looking forward to close the same file from java.
How can I?

PS. I am looking forward for the easiest solution to this problem (there are many answers on how to open a pdf or docx file on stackoverflow but not any about closing the same file.)
Thanks

Comment: In your example you have trued to open .docx file and not a pdf.

Comment: maybe a simple tut? https://www.mkyong.com/java/pdfbox-how-to-read-pdf-file-in-java/

Comment: yes Raj, but logic should be same.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening is easy.

Closing, not so much.

Your current approach starts *some* other program in its own process. Your Java code has no idea what this process is. So you can't easily stop it.

You could do things like:

- query the list of currently running processes
- start the PDF Reader via Desktop
- query the processes again, hoping to identify the one new one

But most likely, the results of doing so would not be accurate.

Beyond that: if you decide to invoke another program, how does your Java code decide "it is time to end that process"? In other words: when you decide to open a PDF using the default PDF viewer in the user's system, then you give up control!

What if that "open" request just adds another tab in a PDF viewer? Do you really think that your Java program should then later kill that whole PDF viewer instance? If I were using your software, I would not like that.

Therefore: the real answer is to either just open PDFs like this. Or to use other approaches, like: using a Java viewer library that gives you full control what gets displayed and how.

Comment: thanks.. Yeah now I have realized that when I open a pdf file or docx file from java, the control is transferred to other program.

Comment: going to try other strategy